# Modify the way files get opened from finder by shift-clicking (etc) as in windows

Tags: windows, macos, windows-registry

In the windows shell it is possible to modify the default action for opening any document type when holding down a modifier key such as shift or option when double clicking. So for example I can open a jpeg in irfanview if I just double click it, in Firefox if I shift-double click it or in Photoshop if I option-double click it.

However on a mac I have to right click, and choose "open with..", which can be annoying when there are a lot of possible candidates (such as with jpegs) or if I want to open the file with something like an applescript, which won't show up on the list and will have to be found in the file system and specified manually, every.. single.. time.

Is there a way of making the mac open files differently by holding down modifier keys when double clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No.

Both those are currently assigned to actions, and I'm not sure you can change them easily.